# Using the Neo4j Server Web Interface for visualization on a Public website

Tags: neo4j, visualization

I'm looking at visualization options for a graph database project that I have coming up.  Part of the job is to provide an interactive visualization of the data for public website visitors.

The standard Neo4j Server Web Interface does all I would need it to and more.  I was wandering if I could simply embed it in a webpage or provide a public url (that could be accessed without a login) that general users could use to view the visualization without being able to edit it or add nodes/relationships?  If you know of any examples of how this can be done, I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: what option you finally used for visualization?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Neo4j browser is an Angular.js application using d3.js as visualization. The code is all open source an on https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.2/community/browser/lib/visualization so you can check it out there.

In general http://maxdemarzi.com is a good source for visualization blog posts as is http://neo4j.org/develop/visualization

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.2/community/browser/lib/visualization/ this is the current version of neo4j visualization

Comment: can you explain how to incorporate neod3.js file in our application so that neo4j browser visualization can be applied to our website ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out Neo4j [GraphGists](http://gist.neo4j.org/). A GraphGist allows you to embed a Neo4j database, Cypher queries, and visualize the results in a web page. Lots of examples listed on the [GraphGist wiki.](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist/wiki)

Comment: it looks like an interesting project but I can't figure out how to use it within an enterprise environment where I'd have to set it up in a local server... any thoughts as to how that would be done?

Comment: GraphGist can not be used independently in a prod environment. It is just a place to reference where you create once and point your users to visualy see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [Mashed Datatoes](http://mdatato.co.in), a bar chart, pie chart like visualization software for Neo4j.

It uses Movie database for demo. Try selecting "Person" as start label.