# Hosting a public (read only) Neo4j instance in the cloud

Tags: neo4j, cloud

I'm working on a open science project to learn why drugs work. We've created a network called [Hetionet](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet) with 47,031 nodes and 2,250,197 relationships. We're [using Neo4j](https://thinklab.com/discussion/using-the-neo4j-graph-database-for-hetnets/112) and have a [GraphGist tutorial](http://portal.graphgist.org/graph_gists/drug-repurposing-by-hetnet-relationship-prediction-a-new-hope) showcasing our approch.

I'd like to let anyone interact with our network. The Neo4j Browser offers the flexibility we want with a nice user interface. So I was thinking a **solution would be to setup a public Neo4j 3.0 Community server** with the settings:

- [`dbms.security.auth_enabled=false`](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/#security-server-auth) to disable login
- [`dbms.read_only=true`](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/#config_dbms.read_only) to prevent write queries
- setting the [Execution Guard](https://dzone.com/articles/10-caveats-neo4j-users-should) to limit query runtime

Here are additional considerations:

1. Cloud hosting: we want to host this in the cloud so it's always available. It looks like AWS would be the cheapest option?
2. Reproducibility: it would be nice if we could make the configuration reproducible and easy to redeploy. [Docker for Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/developer/docker/) that downloads the database [from GitHub](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/tree/31e6cb3162dee8a06085709e730380b52278e32a/hetnet/neo4j)?
3. A killer feature would be linking to or embedding a browser with a prefilled query (see [this unresolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062795)).

So my question is:

- Will there be any problems that prevent hosting a public Neo4j instance?
- Am I on the right track with AWS/Docker?
- Will the setup break under concurrent usage? Let's assume we'll have at most 30 browsers open at once with no more than a few concurrent queries.

Additional notes:

- See related questions [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21506825/4651668) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070585).
- The [Twitter graph demo](http://network.graphdemos.com/) gives similar functionality but creates a new instance for every user.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic for StackOverflow - not a programming question. Plus it's super-broad and opinion-soliciting. And you're asking for recommendations about which cloud to host on.

Answer (score 4):

your ideas all make sense.

You can create a browser-guide for your dataset, e.g. from your graphgist, similar to `:play http://guides.neo4j.com/graphgists`

With this repo you can turn asciidoc (like graphgists) into browser guides: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-guides

Rik did some blog posts on it: http://blog.bruggen.com/2016/03/an-easier-better-tastier-beergraphguide.html

Since 3.0.1, there are even some means to add a form, whose content is then used in the queries.

You have to enable the browser guide in the whitelist in `conf/neo4j.conf`

```
browser.remote_content_hostname_whitelist=http://host:port
```

Since Neo4j 3.0.1 you can setup the browser with an `:play` URL for your users:

```
http://host:7474/browser?cmd=play&arg=http://host:port/path/to/guide.html
```

Regarding Docker, my colleague Ryan just published a docker image for the panama papers that is based on their published database: https://github.com/ryguyrg/panama-neo4j

PS: Feel also free to reach out to me via email michael at neo4j

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @michael-hunger for [setting us](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37377745/4651668) on the right track. We're now publicly hosting Hetionet v1.0 at https://neo4j.het.io.

In short, we used Docker and host the instance on a DigitalOcean Droplet. Here is a [longer discussion with more details](https://thinklab.com/discussion/hosting-hetionet-in-the-cloud-creating-a-public-neo4j-instance/216). You can also check out our [Docker setup](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/tree/6e83b6ea6101bdece408d15079c0ceec1cc5c1e5/hetnet/neo4j/docker) and modified [`neo4j.conf`](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet/blob/6e83b6ea6101bdece408d15079c0ceec1cc5c1e5/hetnet/neo4j/docker/files/neo4j.conf).

Thus far we haven't run into any security or scaling issues. If we do, we'll add those to discussion mentioned above.

Comment: Good work at Daniel! Is the neo4j version you are using at neo4j.het.io the community edition?

Comment: [How do I run the Hetionet v1.0 docker container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405133/how-do-i-run-the-hetionet-v1-0-docker-container)

Comment: @zelusp, currently https://neo4j.het.io is running Neo4j Community Edition version 3.1.0. On [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/dhimmel/hetionet/tags/), we have several different Neo4j versions available. I'd recommend sticking with latest, unless there is a specific reason to use an older image.